# Fuse box in fiat 500e 2017

Tags: fuse, fiat, fuse-panel

The fuse box in fiat 500e 2017 sport package with no panorama, does it required that the box must be full of fuses or it’s normal that there is empty places? As shown in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a legend with the purpose and size of each fuse used.

Some slots are empty on some models of cars depending on the exact equipment specification ie what has been fitted, or not, during build at the factory based on what the customer ordered.

Comment: Yea I understand that, i was afraid that some fuses has been stolen due to empty areas within the fuse box, thanks for your declaration.